# menu and buttons looks messy in Safari - very annoying

Tags: html, css, safari

I hope this thread finds everyone of you healthy.

My page looks fine in all browsers except Safari. 
The problem is with Menu and Buttons. and sometimes with animations. 
For the last several days i am trying to figure out the problem but i failed.

SCREENSHOT: http://s29.postimg.org/6sjchvp4n/safari_problem.png
The page is here http://goo.gl/mpMoNx

If any of you gurus found the solution i will be very thanks full.

EDIT: I found out that if you resize the browser the menu and button gets fixed but when you refresh the page it gets messy again.

Answer (score 0):

Please go in your css file(app.css) and add this css

```
nav > ul > li  { width:auto;}
```

and your menu will work in safari..I have tested too..please check and let me know..thanx

**UPDATED**

[image: Working]

Comment: Hi and thanks for the help but the suggested solution didn't work.
Any modifications in the browser debug panel works but if you save it in the css file and refresh the page, it is not working.

Comment: please add that line so i can inspect in browser..and m sure it will work so kindly add that line please..thanx

Comment: and its working correct..see my updated answer with screenshot.